# sinon: how to stub an instance method

Tags: javascript, node.js, sinon

Here's the code I'm working on:

**Test.js**

```
class Test {
  constructor() {
  }

  func () {
    console.log('original')
  }
}

module.exports = Test
```

**Mock.js**

```
Test = require('./Test')

function Mock(){
  this.test = new Test()
}

Mock.prototype.call = function() {
  this.test.func()
}

module.exports = Mock
```

I'm trying to stub the `Test.func` call that's inside `Mock.call`.  I've tried this:

```
sb = sinon.createSandbox()
sb.stub(Test, 'func').callsFake(() => { console.log('stubbed') })
```

But I get `TypeError: Cannot stub non-existent own property func`.  When I do this:

```
sb.stub(new Test(), 'func').callsFake(() => { console.log('stubbed') })
new Mock().call()
```

I get `original` printed, meaning that the stub did not work properly.  How do I stub out the function call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to stub it on instance which you create:

```
var mock = new Mock();

sinon.stub(mock.test, 'func').callsFake(() => { console.log('stubbed') });
mock.call(); // should output "stubbed"
```

Comment: putting it in the `Mock` constructor isn't an option. this is happening in a test file. I need to stub the function from outside the `Mock` class

Comment: Updated to call it from outside.